# Phrase similar to "in the offing"

Tags: phrases, idioms, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

The meaning of "in the offing" I guess is "something that is likely to happen in the (distant) future"

Is there any phrase that describes something that is likely to happen soon?

Answer (score 2):

Your premise is not correct. According to *Oxford Dictionaries Online* the phrase *[in the offing](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/in-the-offing)* means

> Likely to happen or appear soon:
>   there are several initiatives in the offing

Similarly *[Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/in-the-offing)*

> likely to occur soon

Comment: The origin of the phrase is nautuical, the 'offing' being the deep water between the shore and horizon. Ships 'in the offing' are either about to vanish over the horizon or about to come into harbour. The horizon is between 5-20km away, depending on your vantage point (shore vs clifftop) so something in the offing, is not very far away. http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/in-the-offing.html

Answer (score 1):

**In store (for somebody/something)** — [TFD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+store)

> planned or likely to happen.
>
> *"We have a big surprise in store for you."*
> *"She's got a difficult few months in store, with her husband's illness."*

**In the not too distant future** — [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/in%20the%20not%20too%20distant%20future)

> at a time that is not long from now:  soon
>
> *"Changes are expected in the not too distant future."*

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is ***pending***, something you consider likely to occur in the near-distant future.